# CoreData most recent entries in group

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm wondering if there's a (simple) way to achieve the following using a NSFetchedResultsController:

say I have a visitor log table like this:

```
visitor_name (String)
visit_time (Date)
visited_building_id (String)
```

example data:

```
John, 2015-09-25 10:00:00, ABC
Jane, 2015-09-25 10:20:00, ABC
Mark, 2015-09-25 10:40:00, ABC
Jane, 2015-09-25 10:10:00, DEF
```

And I want to show a table view which shows who most recently visited each building, so for the data above it should show two rows:

```
[ABC, Mark, 9/25 10:40]
[DEF, Jane, 9/25 10:10]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to:

1. Sort the entries by `visited_building_id` (ascending or descending as you prefer) and then by `visit_time` (descending).
2. Specify `visited_building_id` as the `sectionNameKeyPath` for the fetched results controller.  The FRC will therefore have a section for each building, and the first object in each section will be the most recent visit.  You want your table view rows to display the first item in each section of the FRC. So...
3. Amend the tablewView datasource methods to remap the FRC sections to your tableView's rows.  So for example `numberOfRowsInSection` would return `frc.sections.count`.  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would construct a new `NSIndexPath` using

   `NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:(indexPath.row)]`

   or

   `let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:0, inSection:indexPath.row)`

   and uses this `newIndexPath` to obtain the object to display in the cell using the frc's `objectAtIndexPath` method.

Note that this remapping must be repeated/reversed in the other datasource methods. And it also means your tableView can have only one section.

Comment: I think it'll be too inefficient if there are thousands of records, but it's an interesting hack, so I'll accept it.

Comment: You might be able to optimise it with `fetchBatchSize` or even `propertiesToFetch`.  Another option would be to specify `visit_building_id` as the `propertiesToGroupBy`, and `max:(visit_time)` as `propertiesToFetch`.  But you will have to use `NSDictionaryResultType` which means you will have to refetch to get the corresponding `visitor_name`.